# How to compute this double integral

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I'm trying to show that $\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dxdy \neq \int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}dydx$ by computing these integrals directly.

I tried using polar coordinates with no success as the bounds of integration caused problems.

I also tried the substitution $x=ytan\theta$ but ended up getting something of the form $\infty-\infty$.

Can anyone offer a hint as to how I can compute these directly please???

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You don't really need to calculate it though. Just show they're not equal to 0.

Comment: Try to change to polar coordinates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The integral is not absolutely convergent, so we cannot change the order of integration, or the coordinates used, and expect to get the same answer.

---

**Polar Coordinates**

If we try to convert to polar coordinates,
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)\right)\frac1r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&+\int_1^{\sqrt2}\int_{\cos^{-1}\left(\frac1r\right)}^{\sin^{-1}\left(\frac1r\right)}\left(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)\right)\frac1r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\int_0^1\int_0^{\pi/2}\left(\cos^2(\theta)-\sin^2(\theta)\right)\frac1r\,\mathrm{d}\theta\,\mathrm{d}r\\
&=\int_0^10\cdot\frac1r\,\mathrm{d}r\\[6pt]
&=0
\end{align}
$$
The integral for $1\le r\le\sqrt2$ converges absolutely and is equal to its negative under the substitution $\theta\mapsto\frac\pi2-\theta$. Therefore, the integral for $1\le r\le\sqrt2$ is $0$.

The integral for $0\le r\le1$ is equal to $0$ for each $r$, so the integral is $0$ if integrated in $\theta$ first.

Of course, the integral does not converge when integrated in $r$ first since $\int_0^1\frac1r\,\mathrm{d}r$ diverges.

---

**Rectangular Coordinates**
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y
&=\int_0^1\frac1y\int_0^{1/y}\frac{x^2-1}{\left(x^2+1\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=\int_0^1\frac1y\int_0^{\tan^{-1}(1/y)}\left(\sin^2(u)-\cos^2(u)\right)\,\mathrm{d}u\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac1y\left[\sin(u)\cos(u)\vphantom{\frac1y}\right]_0^{\tan^{-1}(1/y)}\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=-\int_0^1\frac1{y^2+1}\,\mathrm{d}y\\[6pt]
&=-\frac\pi4
\end{align}
$$
Similarly, we get
$$
\begin{align}
\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{x^2-y^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}y\,\mathrm{d}x
&=\int_0^1\int_0^1\frac{y^2-x^2}{\left(x^2+y^2\right)^2}\,\mathrm{d}x\,\mathrm{d}y\\[6pt]
&=\frac\pi4
\end{align}
$$

---

Comment: I think you have a tiny error at the start in the first equality. The 1/y should be a 1/y^2, but slight modifications make the proof go through. Thanks again for the post!

Comment: I don't see any error. After the substitution $x\mapsto yx$, there are two factors of $y$ from the numerator, four factors of $y$ from the denominator and one from the $\mathrm{d}x$. That leaves one left over in the denominator.

Comment: Thanks! Missed the y from the substitution.

Answer (score 1):

Put $$f(x,y) = \arctan\left( \tfrac x y \right), \,\,\,\,\,\, (x,y) \in (0,1).$$ We see $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = \frac{1}{1+\left(\tfrac x y \right)^2}\left( - \frac x {y^2} \right) = -\frac{x}{x^2 + y^2}.$$ Then $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} = - \frac{1}{x^2 + y^2} + \frac{x}{(x^2 + y^2)^2}(2x) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$ Next put $$g(x,y) = -\arctan\left( \tfrac y x \right), \,\,\,\,\,\, (x,y) \in (0,1).$$ Then $$\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{1+ \left(-\tfrac{y}{x}\right)^2} \left(\frac{y}{x^2} \right) = \frac{y}{x^2 + y^2}$$ so $$\frac{\partial}{\partial y}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} = \frac{1}{x^2+y^2} - \frac{y}{(x^2+y^2)^2}(2y) = \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2}.$$ Then \begin{align*} \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dx dy &= \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\frac{\partial f}{\partial y} dx dy \\ 
&= \int^1_0 \frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}(1,y) - \frac{\partial f}{ \partial y}(0,y) dy \\
&=- \int^1_0 \frac{1}{1+y^2} dy = - \arctan(1) = - \frac \pi 4
\end{align*} and \begin{align*} \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \frac{x^2 - y^2}{(x^2+y^2)^2} dy dx &= \int^1_0 \int^1_0 \frac{\partial }{\partial y}\frac{\partial g}{\partial x} dy dx \\ 
&= \int^1_0 \frac{\partial g}{ \partial x}(x,1) - \frac{\partial g}{ \partial x}(x,0) dy \\
&= \int^1_0 \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx =  \arctan(1) =  \frac \pi 4.
\end{align*}